# Help finding a Minecraft friend on whatever server that I don't play on or know

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How can I find which minecraft server my friends is playing on?

Answer (score 5):

Ask them is the best way.

There is no way to look up what server they are playing on unless you know the name of it or the ip